# Falling to use TensorCore from Tensorflow Mixed Precision Tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, half-precision-float

I have followed the Mixed precision tutorial from Tensorflow: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/mixed_precision but apparently I fail to use TensorCore. 
My setup:

- Windows 10
- Nvidia driver: 441.87
- python: 3.7
- Cuda: 10.2
- Tensorflow: tf-nightly-gpu=2.2.0-dev20200504 (due to TensorBoard profiling tool: https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras).

As I didn't get any speed up (actually even slower result by adding the mixed precision), I decided to use tenbsorBoard to see if I get any 16 bits computations. Therefore, I slightly modified my code to have more iterations and record some. I have been able to control that indeed I get 0% 16-bit computations.

As it seems straightforward from the Mixed precision tutorial to use those tensor cores, I am wondering what might be the issue in my case. Is there anything that I missing as I am on Windows? Any help welcome

My code (you may need to run it from as Administrator for access writing rights):

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import datetime
 import os.path
  from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models 
from tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision import experimental as mixed_precision 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  # set the policy 
policy = mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_float16') 
mixed_precision.set_policy(policy) 
print('Compute dtype: %s' % policy.compute_dtype) 
print('Variable dtype: %s' % policy.variable_dtype)

  mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist 
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
  
# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1 # 
train_images = train_images.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
 test_images = test_images.reshape(10000, 784).astype('float32') / 255  

# create the model
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(784,), name='digits')
 if tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'):   
    print('The model will run with 4096 units on a GPU')   
    num_units = 4096 
else:   
    # Use fewer units on CPUs so the model finishes in a reasonable amount of time   
    print('The model will run with 64 units on a CPU')   
    num_units = 64 

dense1 = layers.Dense(num_units, activation='relu', name='dense_1')
 x = dense1(inputs)
 dense2 = layers.Dense(num_units, activation='relu', name='dense_2') 
x = dense2(x) 
print('x.dtype: %s' % x.dtype.name) 
# 'kernel' is dense1's variable 
print('dense1.kernel.dtype: %s' % dense1.kernel.dtype.name) 
x = layers.Dense(10, name='dense_logits')(x) 
outputs = layers.Activation('softmax', dtype='float32', name='predictions')(x) 
print('Outputs dtype: %s' % outputs.dtype.name)
 model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)  

# Compile and train the model 
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), 
    metrics=['accuracy'])

  log_dir = os.path.join("logs", "fit_MNIST", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")) tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, 
    histogram_freq=1, 
    profile_batch='400, 600')  

initial_weights = model.get_weights() 

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=64, epochs=5, 
    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), 
    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])  

# evaluate
test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2) 
print(test_acc)
```

And the log

```
C:\Users\Michael\PycharmProjects\BVS>py -3.7 -m MNIST.train
2020-05-06 09:53:59.760686: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:01.903395: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:01.940372: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1544] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:65:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.545GHz coreCount: 68 deviceMemorySize: 11.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 573.69GiB/s
2020-05-06 09:54:01.953851: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:01.967405: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:01.982849: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:01.989259: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:02.000515: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:02.008599: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:02.036045: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:02.042418: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1686] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-05-06 09:54:02.048313: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with Intel(R) MKL-DNN to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-05-06 09:54:02.081395: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x17acc96b860 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-05-06 09:54:02.087398: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-05-06 09:54:02.093847: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1544] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:65:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.545GHz coreCount: 68 deviceMemorySize: 11.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 573.69GiB/s
2020-05-06 09:54:02.104982: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:02.109817: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:02.115502: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:02.119405: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:02.125012: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:02.129275: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:02.135712: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:02.140090: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1686] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-05-06 09:54:02.818915: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1085] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-05-06 09:54:02.826267: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1091]      0
2020-05-06 09:54:02.832173: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1104] 0:   N
2020-05-06 09:54:02.837490: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1230] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 8584 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2020-05-06 09:54:02.860430: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x17aee2fe5b0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-05-06 09:54:02.867611: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, Compute Capability 7.5
Compute dtype: float16
Variable dtype: float32
The model will run with 4096 units on a GPU
x.dtype: float16
dense1.kernel.dtype: float32
Outputs dtype: float32
2020-05-06 09:54:03.793536: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:154] Profiler session started.
2020-05-06 09:54:03.798555: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1372] Profiler found 1 GPUs
2020-05-06 09:54:03.806491: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cupti64_101.dll
2020-05-06 09:54:03.933366: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1494] CUPTI activity buffer flushed
Epoch 1/5
2020-05-06 09:54:04.667227: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
397/938 [===========>..................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.3610 - accuracy: 0.90472020-05-06 09:54:09.555345: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:154] Profiler session started.
596/938 [==================>...........] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3028 - accuracy: 0.9194WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\summary_ops_v2.py:1277: stop (from tensorflow.python.eager.profiler) is deprecated and will be removed after 2020-07-01.
Instructions for updating:
use `tf.profiler.experimental.stop` instead.
2020-05-06 09:54:12.391419: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1494] CUPTI activity buffer flushed
2020-05-06 09:54:12.449130: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/device_tracer.cc:217]  GpuTracer has collected 32964 callback api events and 32964 activity events.
2020-05-06 09:54:13.421652: I tensorflow/core/profiler/rpc/client/save_profile.cc:168] Creating directory: logs\fit_MNIST\20200506-095403\train\plugins\profile\2020_05_06_07_54_12
2020-05-06 09:54:13.918583: I tensorflow/core/profiler/rpc/client/save_profile.cc:174] Dumped gzipped tool data for trace.json.gz to logs\fit_MNIST\20200506-095403\train\plugins\profile\2020_05_06_07_54_12\DESKTOP-AEJL5TN.trace.json.gz
2020-05-06 09:54:14.366916: I tensorflow/core/profiler/utils/event_span.cc:288] Generation of step-events took 0.508 ms

2020-05-06 09:54:14.414129: I tensorflow/python/profiler/internal/profiler_wrapper.cc:110] Creating directory: logs\fit_MNIST\20200506-095403\train\plugins\profile\2020_05_06_07_54_12Dumped tool data for overview_page.pb to logs\fit_MNIST\20200506-095403\train\plugins\profile\2020_05_06_07_54_12\DESKTOP-AEJL5TN.overview_page.pb
Dumped tool data for input_pipeline.pb to logs\fit_MNIST\20200506-095403\train\plugins\profile\2020_05_06_07_54_12\DESKTOP-AEJL5TN.input_pipeline.pb
Dumped tool data for tensorflow_stats.pb to logs\fit_MNIST\20200506-095403\train\plugins\profile\2020_05_06_07_54_12\DESKTOP-AEJL5TN.tensorflow_stats.pb
Dumped tool data for kernel_stats.pb to logs\fit_MNIST\20200506-095403\train\plugins\profile\2020_05_06_07_54_12\DESKTOP-AEJL5TN.kernel_stats.pb

938/938 [==============================] - 15s 16ms/step - loss: 0.2555 - accuracy: 0.9325 - val_loss: 0.1904 - val_accuracy: 0.9584
Epoch 2/5
938/938 [==============================] - 12s 13ms/step - loss: 0.1268 - accuracy: 0.9696 - val_loss: 0.2004 - val_accuracy: 0.9634
Epoch 3/5
938/938 [==============================] - 12s 13ms/step - loss: 0.0966 - accuracy: 0.9776 - val_loss: 0.1817 - val_accuracy: 0.9666
Epoch 4/5
938/938 [==============================] - 12s 12ms/step - loss: 0.0850 - accuracy: 0.9813 - val_loss: 0.1250 - val_accuracy: 0.9748
Epoch 5/5
938/938 [==============================] - 12s 13ms/step - loss: 0.0710 - accuracy: 0.9848 - val_loss: 0.1980 - val_accuracy: 0.9714
313/313 - 1s - loss: 0.1980 - accuracy: 0.9714
0.9714000225067139
```